# Compare two names (strings) having different order of names and initials

Tags: string, compare

I am comparing two Names.

NAME1 = J SMITH
NAME2 = SMITH J

Same name but in different order.

String.compare doesn't equate them and rightly so.

But in my case I want a function which would class this comparison as true ignoring the order of the words as long as Names and Initials are the same.

Any idea how to do this

```
 If InvName.Split(" ").Sort() = BankName.Split(" ").Sort() Then
            Return True
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

So a string sort on both and then compare them.

```
Array.Sort(Name.Split(" ")) = Array.Sort(Name2.Split(" "))
```

Comment: How do i do that? vb.net

Comment: Show what you have done so far, if you still cannot code it, then I can adjust it for you.

Comment: if NAME1.Split(" ").Sort() = NAME2.Split(" ").Sort() then ?

Comment: If InvName.Split(" ").Sort() = BankName.Split(" ").Sort() Then
                Return True
            End If

Comment: But it is asking for arguments/Parameters for Sort function

Comment: Excellent!  I got a bit fuzzy when I am using multiple languages.  VB.Net is my favourite, but sadly, I spend most of my time in C# these days.  Don't forget to mark as answered if it resolved your problem.